# Baking normals for this curved cylinder is creating these odd wavey lines in the normal map

Tags: texturing, baking, normal-map

[image]

As you can see from the image below, the normal map on the right side of the screenshot is producing these weird horizontal waves on my texture.
Any form of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have described how a normal map looks, but have not described any problems with it. Normal maps are usually not used to frame and hang on the wall and then admire so their looks are not usually as important as the function. They are usually used to define surface direction - do you have any problems with that? What are the problems? Could you describe what you expect to achieve and how the result you get differs from your expectations and provide some pictures to illustrate your actual problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5OstvAY

The image normal map is creating these weird wavey horizontal lines instead of being completely smooth.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the normal map looks like. It is made according to whatever the geometry is. You don't need to look at it. It's not a picture, just values saved in a picture format. Use it, see if the result gives you problems.

Comment: Hello :). Please add an example of such normal map applied to your mesh, to show if there are any problems.